# Class implementing an interface that extends from autcloseable

Tags: java, java-11

I have a class that implements an interface that extends from autocloseable. My doubt is, only the methods from my interface will be autocloseable or the methods from my class (and not from the interface) will be autocloseable too?

Comment: It's not about methods. Your class, through an intermediate interface, implements `AutoCloseable`. That means your _class_ declares itself to be `AutoCloseable` and must implement that interface's method (i.e. `#close()`). It also means, by special virtue of the `AutoCloseable` interface, that instances of your class can be used in try-with-resources statements.

Comment: Object instances are auto-closeable, methods are not. When an object instance is auto-closeable, it must implement the `close()` method of the [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface, and can be used in a **try-with-resources** statement.

Comment: I get you, so just because my class implements an interface that extends from Autocloseable the whole class is autocloseable right? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confused about inheritance.

```
interface MyInterface{
  void method();
}

class Super implements MyInterface{
  /* must be implemented. If it's not, then it would NOT also be a MyInterface type */
  public void method(){ ... }
}

class SubClass extends Super {
  // if nothing is added, then only the methods from Super will be a part of SubClass.
  // that means method() is part of this class.
  // It also implements MyInterface, because Super does.
}
```

So you can call method like this:

```
// SubClass is a SubClass type, a Super type and a MyInterface type
MyInterface test = new SubClass();  
test.method();
```

The `AutoCloseable` interface only has one method `void close()` and that has to be implemented by any class that directly declares `implements AutoClosable`. Every class that inherits from that class is also an `AutoClosable` type and automatically has an implemented `public close()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of `AutoCloseable`: it is not per method, but per object or rather per resource holder:

```
try (YourAutoCloseable aut = new YourAutoCloseable(...)) {
  ...
} // close is called somewhere after this '}'
```

That's more of a compiler interface allowing your object to be used as a resource in a try-with-resource. It does not mean you have to use in try-with-resource, but that you should.

This is like `Iterable` for `foreach`.